# Configure logstash.conf to listen to HTTPS

Tags: elasticsearch, https, logstash, serilog, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to set up the basic Elk Stack: ElasticSearch with Kibana and Logstash together with a **.NET Standard 2.1 Blazor WebAssembly Hosted** application.

I use Serilog for logging, but I don't want to use the **Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch** NuGet package, because it seems not to work with the current Blazor WebAssembly release.

Thus I want to use **Serilog.Sinks.Http** to trace the HTTPS requests.

My application structure looks like this:

- BlazorApp.Client (https://localhost:0815)
- BlazorApp.Server (https://localhost:1234)

I can send logs from my Client to my Server app using the Serilog Sinks Http plugin.

Currently I'm struggling to correctly configure the `logstash.conf` file to listen to HTTPS calls. I want to use the installed [Http Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-logstash-input-http-plugin)

```
input {
    http {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => 1234
        ssl => on
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstash_http"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

When I start logstash with **logstash -f logstash.conf** my Logstash API starts and shuts down immediately.

Unfortunately I don't know where Visual Studio is putting the SSL/TLS key for apps simply running under HTTPS on localhost.

Do you know how to correctly configure logstash to listen to HTTPS calls on localhost?

Comment: What is in the log when you start logstash? I don't know Blazor, but is your BlazorApp.Server binding to the port `1234`? You can't use the same port for your logstash http input if another service is using this port.

Comment: yes, http://localhost:1234 is the URI of the BlazorApp.Server app. Thus, I'll need a random other port for the input? ...I thought that's the port to listen to...

Comment: The port in the http input is the port that logstash will bind and listen for http requests, if you choose `1234` for it, you will need to change the port in your app, you can't use the same port twice.